# Using Intersection observer to highlight active link isn't consistent

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, nuxt.js

I have a aside section with anchor links on the left and content on the right. What I want to do is to highlight the anchor link when the user scrolls to a particular text that's anchored.

I am using Intersection Observer for this feature. However, the problem is that on scroll it's all working fine, but when you click the anchor, the active class doesn't trigger properly. That's because the paragraphs that I am observing are all different sizes.

Some of them are taller, some smaller. So if I have 2 paragraphs that are small and right close to each other, the class doesn't trigger on a link which I clicked.

I think I'd need some dynamic thershold or margins but I am not sure how to do this.

For example, on this site it works really well even though the paragpraphs are close to each other: https://n26.com/en-eu/blog/bike-tours-europe#france-champagne-region

```
 async highlightAnchorOnScroll() {
      if (window.matchMedia('(min-width:768px)')) {
        await new Promise((resolve) =>
          setTimeout(() => {
            let observerOptions = {
              threshold: 0.5,
              rootMargin: '0px 0px -50% 0px',
            }

            const list = document.querySelectorAll('.b-anchor')

            this.$options.observer = new IntersectionObserver(
              observerCallback,
              observerOptions
            )
            const asideLinks = document.querySelectorAll('.aside ul li')

            function observerCallback(entries) {
              entries.forEach((entry, index) => {
               

                if (entry.isIntersecting) {
                  asideLinks.forEach((el) => {
                    if (
                      entry.target.previousSibling.children[0].innerText.trim() ===
                      el.innerText.trim()
                    ) {
                      el.classList.add('activeLink')
                    } else {
                      el.classList.remove('activeLink')
                    }
                  })
                }
              })
            }

            Array.from(list).forEach((element, index) => {
              this.$options.observer.observe(element.nextElementSibling)
            })
          }, 200)
        )
      }
    },
```

Code when clicking on anchor

```
 scrollToElement(refName) {
  const test = document.getElementById(refName)
  const y = window.pageYOffset + test.getBoundingClientRect().top - 200
  // document.getElementById(refName).getBoundingClientRect().top - 200

  window.scroll({
    top: y,
    behavior: 'smooth',
  })
},
```

Comment: Have I misunderstood, because I can't see why you don't just change the highlighting on the anchor link when it is clicked (and remove it from elsewhere of course)? Could you show us the basic HTML structure it may make it easier to see what the problem is. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Since I am using intersection observer, it doesn't matter if I click on it because it should highlight the anchor when the corresponding text appears in the viewport.

Comment: But the problem, as  you have described as well, is that several elements may be in the viewport and you don't know from IntersectionObserver which one is the one whose link they have clicked. So, you need another way of knowing, and that way is the onclick event on a particular link.

Comment: Could you show us the code you are using when a link is clicked? How are you remembering that this has been done so Intersection Observer is not doing anything just that time?

Comment: added the code when you click on the anchor link

Comment: Why are you removing 200 pixels from the top when you force that scroll? It means the item immediately above is bound to still be (albeit maybe only partly) in the viewport so your code will highlight it as the chosen one.

Comment: The reason is so the section has some spacing and isn't glued to the top of the page for better reading.

Comment: I understand, but doing that means that the section above must be in the viewport and so will get highlighted. You will need to remember that you've done this.